# syslog stops logging after log rotation

Tags: linux, logging, freebsd, syslog, logrotate

Every time after newsyslog rotates the log file, syslog stops logging into the file. Until a syslogd restart is done.

```
(myserver:wheel)# logger -p local1.info -t myprocess "hello thiru"; ll myfile.log; cat myfile.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     0B Nov 10 11:26 myfile.log

(myserver:wheel)# /etc/rc.d/syslogd restart
Stopping syslogd.
Starting syslogd.

(myserver:wheel)# logger -p local1.info -t myprocess "hello thiru"; ll myfile.log; cat myfile.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    44B Nov 10 12:04 myfile.log
Nov 10 12:04:31 myserver myprocess: hello thiru 
(myserver:wheel)#
```

On `Linux` (which uses `logrotate`), we can solve this by doing `syslog/rsyslog restart` in the `postrotate` section of the logroate conf.

Is there something similar to `postrotate` in `newsyslog`?

**Edit:**

Syslog and newsyslog conf files:

```
(TPC-E11-36:wheel)# cat /etc/newsyslog.d/newsyslog-myprocess.conf
/var/log/myfile.log 644 20 10000 * Z

(TPC-E11-36:wheel)# cat /etc/syslog.d/syslog-myprocess.conf
!myprocess
local1.info /var/log/myfile.log
(TPC-E11-36:wheel)#
```

Comment: See `man newsyslog.conf`, but by default `syslogd` receives a signal when a log file is rotated unless either an `N` flag or **another process** has been specified. Check your `newsyslog.conf` or `newsyslog.conf.d/*` files.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't know how to specify a process in `newsyslog.conf`? And I haven't used `N` flag either.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. If I add your lines to my `/etc/syslog.conf` and invoke `newsyslog -f newsyslog-cnd.conf`, the logfile is rotated, a new one is created with a message `logfile turned over due to size` and `logger` works fine into the new file. I do not recognise your subdirectories `newsyslog.d` and `syslog.d` and I do not get a `0B` file after log rotation.

Comment: @RichardSmith I too can't replicate it now :( Is it possible that this happened because of Daylight Saving Time change?

And please ignore the sub directories. My syslog.conf and newsyslog.conf include them.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path of the pidfile into the  `/etc/newsyslog.conf` and if required a signal for example `1` that stands for `SIGHUP`, more info about newsyslog here: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-syslog.html

The format/example is this:

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]

/var/log/your-app.log   root:wheel      600  7     *    @T00  GBJC  /var/run/your-app.pid 1
```

Also see this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/701563/94862

Answer (score 1):

There is actually something similar to postrotate in newsyslog, it's the **R** flag in the configuration file in combination with *path_to_pid_cmd_file* (that's what it's called in the FreeBSD manual entry of newslog.conf(5)). With this flag set, the path provided will not be interpreted as a path to a PID file, but as a path to a script (for example a shell script) which will be executed after the log rotation is finished.

You can even pass arguments to the script, but for this you'll have to use the IFS-variable (separated by a space, the argument would be interpreted as a signal and likely throw an error).

```
# logfilename       [owner:group] mode count size  when  flags [/cmd_file]
/var/log/myfile.log root:wheel    644  20    10000 *     ZR    /path/to/my/script${IFS}myargument
```